# jQuery: parseXML appendChild "Type mismatch"-error IE8

Tags: jquery, xml, appendchild

I want to create a XML-file with some data, but IE8 throwsout an error. With FF and Chrome my script works. Any idea why `col.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this))` doesn't work with IE8?

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><mapping-table/>");
//Append rows with col to XML-document
    $.each(trData, function(){
        var row = xmlDoc.createElement('row');
        $.each(this, function(){
            var col = xmlDoc.createElement('col');          
            col.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this));
            row.appendChild(col);
        });
        xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(row);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method `createElement` on your XML document, which is fine.

But you are creating your text node in the scope of your (html) `document` object – instead of creating it in the scope of your XML document as well.

Use `xmlDoc.createTextNode` instead.